# What does 'make of' mean in the sentence?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Does it mean 'to have or form an opinion about(Merriam-Webster)' or just literally 'create from'?

> Sean Covey, an American business executive and author, wrote, "You are
> free to choose what you want to ***make of*** your life. It's called
> free agency or free will, and it's your birthright."

Comment: Did you intend to leave a link under "(Meriam-Webster)"?

Answer (score 2):

This does NOT mean "to have or form an opinion about". The closest definition in M-W appears to be [16a](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/make):

> to produce as a result of action, effort, or behavior with respect to something

There are two examples:

> make a mess of the job
> tried to make a thorough job of it

The object of the preposition "of" is the thing out of which you make something. In M-W's examples, the OOTPs are "the job" and "it". In your sentence, the OOTP is "your life".

The direct object of "make" is the final result. In M-W's examples, the DOs are "a mess" and "a thorough job". In your sentence, the DO is the pronoun "what".

Comment: A perfect explanation! Thank you, MarcinManhattan.